# Limit the set of selected fields to those of the target subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, discriminator

I'm using single table inheritance, one parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class Parent {
  // ...
}
```

and two child entities:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child1")
public class Child1 extends Parent {
  @Column(name = "child1_property")
  private Integer child1Property;
  // ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child2")
public class Child2 extends Parent {
  @Column(name = "child2_property")
  private Integer child2Property;
  // ...
}
```

Now, if I query (HQL) directly from `Child1` entity:

```
from Child1
```

it will generate an SQL that selects only the columns from `Parent` entity plus `Child1` entity. If I select from `Parent` entity using a `where type='child1'`

```
from Parent p where type(p)='child1'
```

it will return only `Child1` entities but the SQL query selects all columns from `Parent`, `Child1` and `Child2`. Is there a possibility to query from `Parent` entity use the discriminator column (i.e. limit only to `Child1` entities) and get a specific SQL query, i.e. that will select only columns from `Parent` and `Child1`.

Comment: Maybe you can show your HQL query?

Comment: Why can't you just use `from Child1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A projection seems to work:

```sql
SELECT new fully.qualified.name.of.Child1(p.id, p.name, p.child1Property)
  FROM Parent p
 WHERE TYPE(p) = 'child1'
```

produces

```sql
    select
        parent0_.id as col_0_0_,
        parent0_.name as col_1_0_,
        parent0_.child1_property as col_2_0_ 
    from
        parent parent0_ 
    where
        parent0_.type='child1'
```

Hibernate User Guide [excerpt](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause):

> There is a particular expression type that is only valid in the select clause. Hibernate calls this "*dynamic instantiation*". JPQL supports some of that feature and calls it a "*constructor expression*".
>
> So rather than dealing with the Object[] (again, see Hibernate Query API) here, we are wrapping the values in a type-safe Java object that will be returned as the results of the query.
>
> ...
>
> **The projection class must be fully qualified in the entity query, and it must define a matching constructor.**
>
> The class here need not be mapped. It can be a DTO class.
>
> If it does represent an entity, the resulting instances are returned in the NEW state (not managed!).

However, I'd just `SELECT c FROM Child1 c`. I was actually surprised that Hibernate didn't complain about the attribute `child1Property` missing for the entity `Parent`.